# How to avoid Windows 7 wake up screen?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

When Windows 7 hibernates and then I wake it up, it always shows a screen where I have to click before I can get into the Windows environment. I don't have a password set so this intermediate screen serves no purpose - just one wasted mouse click and an unnecessary wait every time. How do I disable this so that I go from hibernating directly into my desktop without a click?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In control panel go:

1. Hardware and sound
2. Power settings
3. Change plan settings
4. Change advanced power settings
5. Change 'require password on wakeup' to no