# Bypass login screen after sleeping or hibernating

Tags: windows-7, user

I don't have password set for a public computer.

Is there a way to auto unlock the computer after hibernating or sleeping so I don't have to press the user? This is what my login screen looks like:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Windows 7 wake up screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/152760/), [How to disable the welcoming screen for when PC wakes up](http://superuser.com/questions/674126/), [How to automatically log in after sleep](http://superuser.com/questions/631286/).

Comment: Official related article: [How do I change the password requirement when my computer wakes from sleep?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-password-requirement-computer-wakes#1TC=windows-7)

Answer (score 7):

- Open Control Panel
- Choose `Power Options` (all control panel items)
- Click on `Require a password on wakeup` (on the left)
- Click `Change settings that are currently unavailable`
- Enter your password if needed
- Check `Don't require a password`

[image]

---

As it is a public computer, if you haven't already, you probably want to [set up auto-login](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/auto-logon-windows-7.htm) to the only account on the computer